# How do I create a div tag heading with a underline?

Tags: css

See Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Css

If you look at the heading, it says "Cascading Style Sheets", then it has an underline.

**How do you do that?**

```
.heading1 {
/* heading with underline */
}
```

Comment: you could simply look at the source of wikipedia :P

Comment: You should install Firebug - it's trivially easy to use its inspector to look at the CSS for a particular element.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use borders:

```
.heading1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

And if you're using Firefox, get Firebug which allows you to inspect any element's CSS attributes so you don't have to guess how a certain style is implemented.

Comment: You should change `.heading1{...}` to `h1 {...}`.

Answer (score 8):

just add in the css: `text-decoration: underline;`

Answer (score 4):

```
h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the div is 100% wide the you can put a bottom border

```
.heading1 {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
   width:100%;
}
```

As everyone said get firebug, you can also use google chrome's integrated inspector(which is like firebug).

Comment: Or Safari's integrated inspector, as well. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

The border is the wrong (amateur) way to do it. Better use the "hr" tag. It makes an underline a width of the parent div. Put it after the text or heading you want to be underlined. Live example:

## Cascading Style Sheets

---

The code would look like this (oversimplified, of course):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Underline</title>
</head>
 <body>
  <p>Hello</p><hr>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!